# ¿Cómo evitar la perdida de precisión al trabajar con datos flotantes en Java?

Tags: java

```
public class OperArit3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    double c = 12/(3+2)*2-1;

    System.out.println("c = " + c);
```

El IDE Netbeans me da como resultado 3.0

Al realizar la operación de forma manual claramente vemos que el Resultado es: 3.8

12/(3+2)*2-1
12/5*2-1(primero resuelve el paréntesis)
2.4*2-1 (luego hace la división)
4.8-1(después multiplica)
3.8 (finalmente resta)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La razón por la que te da 3 es porque la operaciones con enteros van a resultar en enteros. `12/(3+2)*2-1` tiene solamente enteros, y por lo tanto el resultado será entero también (El resultado es `3`)

La solución entonces sería hacer algún operando de tipo flotante. Alguno pero no cualquiera, hay que elegir sabiamente, porque si hacemos `12/(3+2)*2-1f`, el resultado ahora será `3.0`.

Obviamente no es lo que queremos. El meollo del asunto está en la división, por lo que hacer lo siguiente es más que suficiente `12d/(3+2)*2-1`, de hecho es equivalente que hacer `12/(3d+2)*2-1` o `12/(3+2d)*2-1`.

El sufijo `d` y `f` indican que el dato no es entero sino `double` y `float`, respectivamente. Eso es equivalente a la respuesta de Hamada, o sea `(double) 12/(3+2)*2-1` que castea el `12` como entero a `12` como `double`

Si se quiere trabajar aún con más precisión, se puede usar [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Por último te invito a investigar porqué `12d/(3+2)*2-1 != 12f/(3+2)*2-1`.

Answer (score 0):

En la integración, no se expresa el resultado exacto, no se debe inferir sino determinar en la programación orientada a objetos

```
double c = (double) 12/(3+2)*2-1;
```